# Fetch number of rows and other column value in single oracle query

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

Consider i have below tables called Book_detail and Author_detail:

| Id | BookId | Name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1001 | ABC |
| 2 | 2001 | XYZ |

| Price | BookId | Name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | 1001 | Sham |
| 200 | 2001 | Ram |

I want below result:

| countA | countB | id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2 |

I tried below but not working:

```
Select (select count(*) from Author_Detail where BookId = 2001) as countA,
       (select count(*) as countB, Id as id from Book_Detail where BookId = 2 group by Id) 
from dual;
```

Answer (score 0):

With sample data you posted:

```
SQL> with
  2  book_detail (id, bookid, name) as
  3    (select 1, 1001, 'ABC' from dual union all
  4     select 2, 2001, 'XYZ' from dual
  5    ),
  6  author_detail (price, bookid, name) as
  7    (select 100, 1001, 'Sham' from dual union all
  8     select 200, 2001, 'Ram'  from dual union all
  9     select 300, 3001, 'xxx'  from dual
 10    )
 11  select count(a.bookid) counta,
 12         count(distinct b.id) countb,
 13         b.id
 14  from book_detail b join author_detail a on a.bookid = b.bookid
 15  where a.bookid = 2001
 16  group by b.id;

    COUNTA     COUNTB         ID
---------- ---------- ----------
         1          1          2

SQL>
```